# Team Create search bar isn't shown

Tags: roblox

So.. I'd like to make a game with some friend of mine and the trouble is, when I open Team Create, the search bar simply isn't shown and I can not add him. What should I do ?[image: Team Create Bug]
The game is published, set on public, Team Create ON and, of course, I am the game owner

Comment: The functionality was moved, look in GameSettings > Permissions to add your friend.

Comment: I've checked that out and it works! Thank you!!